# Pass Cucumber feature parameters in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, cucumber

I just wondering how can I set Cucumber test parameters when running them directly in IntelliJ

```
IntelliJ version - 13.0.1
Gradle 1.5
```

I tried to set them via Edit Configuration, not worked though

The way I pass them when run in command line is as below. It's working fine.

```
$gradle cucumber -Ptags=@<Scenario Name> -Penv=<Running test env.>
```

As we can run the Feature scenario directly in IDE, The first parameter of course no need to pass. The question is the second one.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an appropriate configuration for all as well single test. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) is how to do it. In configuration window there'll be field 'Program arguments'. This is where You can pass required arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still try to figure out the way should place the argument. I tried ` --format org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome --name "-Ptags=@RandD -Penv=<env name>"`. But no luck. The first part was already there in that Program argument field

Comment: Any sample project on GitHub for instance?

Comment: Sorry, Unfortunately not. Above setting gave me this error. ` None of the features at [path../src/test/resources/features/RD.feature] matched the filters: [-Ptags=@RandD -Penv=xxx]`

Comment: my feature file is `Feature: Research And Development
@RandD
Scenario: Research 1
Given I am doing research
Then I get the results`

Comment: Hard to help without test env and no idea how to set it up. Have never used cucumber.